# Performance analysis in puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am running puppeteer for web crawling..i need to analyse a webpage performance using puppeteer..

i need time split up for each component in puppeteer like timetaken for making connection to a url,timetaken for page.evaluate method etc..

I would also like to know ,is there any node module for the same?

Answer (score 3):

How is it going?

> I would also like to know ,is there any node module for the same?

I've tried some modules on npm repository, but none of them fits my needs. Try searching npm by "puppeteer performance" or "puppeteer metrics". See if one of them fits your need.

What I ended up doing is creating my own scheme of gathering metrics, using a combination of `Date.now() - t0` (where t0 is my previous Date.now()) for code running on node, and `await page.evaluate(() => performance.now());` for code running on Page.

Other things that you may try are:

- npm module puppeteer-har: you can generate HAR files very easy with it.
- puppeteer Tracing: see page.tracing.start and page.tracing.stop. With it you can generate "tracings", that you can open on chrome devtools "Performance" tab.
- Chrome Devtools Protocol: `let { metrics: cdpMetrics } = await page._client.send('Performance.getMetrics');`  This collects various metrics from page loading.

Again, for do what you want:

> i need time split up for each component in puppeteer like timetaken for making connection to a url,timetaken for page.evaluate method etc..

Chances are that your best shot is instrumenting the code by yourself using Date.now().  :)